# IDB: openCursor() is not a function

Tags: javascript, cursor, indexeddb

Well, maybe I do something wrong... But this error is very confusing. I stick with: "Uncaught TypeError: requestChatHistory.openCursor is not a function at IDBOpenDBRequest.dbPromise.onsuccess"

IDBOpenRequest might inherit methods from IDBRequest...

I tried to make request without openCursor() and get the first value from it.
Also tried to re-create database, use different browsers (Chrome, Edge, Firefox)

onUpgrade promise:

```
dbPromise.onupgradeneeded = function(event) { 
        let db = event.target.result;
        db.createObjectStore('keys', {keyPath: 'userId'});
        let chatHistory = db.createObjectStore('messages', { keyPath: "id", autoIncrement:true });
        chatHistory.createIndex("chatId", "chatId", { unique: false });
    };
```

There is my function with request:

```
async function loadSavedMessages(chatId){
        let dbPromise = idb.open('clientDB', 3);
        dbPromise.onsuccess = function() {
            let db = this.result;
            let dbTransaction = db.transaction(["messages"]);
            let messages = dbTransaction.objectStore("messages");
            let index = messages.index('chatId'); 
            let requestChatHistory = index.get(chatId);
            requestChatHistory.openCursor().onsuccess = function(event) {
                let cursor = event.target.result;
                if (cursor) {
                    console.log(cursor);
                    cursor.continue();
                }
            };
        }
    }
```

Function that saves data:

```
async function saveMessage(chatId, message, userId){
        let dbPromise = idb.open('clientDB', 3);
        dbPromise.onsuccess = function() {
            let db = this.result;
            let dbTransaction = db.transaction(["messages"], 'readwrite');
            let messages = dbTransaction.objectStore("messages");
            let mesObj = {
                chatId: chatId,
                user: userId,
                message: message,
                timestamp: Date.now()
            };
            let save = messages.add(mesObj);
            save.onerror = function(event) {
                // Handle errors!
                console.log("Something went wrong with local DB :(")
            };
            save.onsuccess = function(event) {
                // Do something with the request.result!
                console.log(`Message saved, id ${save.result}`);
            };
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is your problem:

```
            let requestChatHistory = index.get(chatId);
            requestChatHistory.openCursor().onsuccess = function(event) {
```

`requestChatHistory` is an [`IDBRequest`](https://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/#request-api), which has no `openCursor` method. `openCursor` is on [`IDBIndex`](https://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/#index-interface), like your `index` variable. So maybe you meant to do something like:

```
            index.openCursor(chatId).onsuccess = function(event) {
```